# How to change order increment id

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I made research many things about change increment order id. i tried extension also but nothing helps me to achieve like this.

I want it like `10000001` to `10001`.

The orders are already there might not affected but if i place new order than the increment id should be `10002`

Any help will appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//Try with below query. please first try with testing site.

//Replace the X‘s with your desired order number and run the query.

UPDATE eav_entity_store
INNER JOIN eav_entity_type ON eav_entity_type.entity_type_id = eav_entity_store.entity_type_id
SET eav_entity_store.increment_last_id='XXXXXXXXXX'
WHERE eav_entity_type.entity_type_code='order';

More details refer this link : 
[enter link description here](https://www.warpconduit.net/2012/04/18/how-to-change-the-order-increment-id-and-prefix-in-magento/)

Comment: Ok thank you.. it is working before your answer,, but it is appreciated,,